# Netbeans Swing Draggable Panel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, panel

I'm trying to make a node based editor similar to Twine or Yarn. How do make a draggable box/panel using Swing in Netbeans?

Is it possible to draw and drag boxes within the Canvas?

Comment: Draggable how?  Frames are normally draggable, so what are you actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drag components around a panel then you need to:

1. Use a null layout on the panel. This means you are now responsible for setting the size and location of any component you add to the panel. Note, it is never a good idea to use a null layout so you may want to instead use the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) which helps with the layout features. It will manage the size and you just worry about the location.
2. Add a MouseListener to each component you want to drag so you can handle the mouseDragged event.

Check out [Moving Windows](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) for a simple class that just does dragging.

Or, you can use the more advanced `ComponentMover` class that supports additional functionality.

Basic drag listener:

```
public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
    {
        pressed = me;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        component.setLocation(x, y);
     }
}
```

The code to use this class would be:

```
DragListener drag = new DragListener();
component.addMouseListener( drag );
component.addMouseMotionListener( drag );
```

The drag listener can be shared by all components.